# Why does AES decryptor always returns 16 zeros (in 16 bytes)?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

My goal is to get a very simple block cipher, that is, the
Core of AES. It must take a key and a block and return a block. The decryptor should take the key and the block an return the original block.

I have been testing with the following key (in hex)

```
AA000000000000000000000000000000
```

and the following plain text

```
AA000000000000000000000000000000
```

(again in hex, and yes, the same as the key)

The result should be

```
814827A94525FF24B90F20BEC065866D
```

and indeed it is. (You can verify here that that should be the result at http://www.cryptogrium.com/aes-encryption-online-ecb.html with this as input and selecting AES-128).

But the decryptor always returns

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

(Only zeros).

What I'm I doing wrong in the following implementation? This implementation is only for educational purposes. That is why I used ECB mode and why I'm expecting always the same encryption.

```
namespace CryptographyCSharp
{
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class MyAes
{
    public static string EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string msg_hex, string key_hex)
    {
        if (msg_hex == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("msg_hex");
        if (key_hex == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key_hex");

        byte[] output = new byte[16];
        msg_hex = msg_hex.PadRight(32, '0');
        key_hex = key_hex.PadRight(32, '0');
        using (var aes = Aes.Create("AES"))
        {
            
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 128;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            if (!aes.ValidKeySize(128))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key_hex.hex2bytes(), null);
            encryptor.TransformBlock(msg_hex.hex2bytes(), 0, 16, output, 0);
            encryptor.Dispose();
        }

        return output.tohex();
    }

    public static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(string hex_ct, string key_hex)
    {
        if (hex_ct == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (key_hex == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        hex_ct = hex_ct.PadRight(32, '0');
        key_hex = key_hex.PadRight(32, '0');
        string plaintext = null;

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create("AES"))
        {
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 128;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            if (!aes.ValidKeySize(128))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(key_hex.hex2bytes(), null);
            var output = new byte[16];
            decryptor.TransformBlock(hex_ct.hex2bytes(), 0, 16, output, 0);
            plaintext = output.tohex();
        }

        return plaintext;
    }
}
}
```

I have used some extension methods that transform hex to bytes and viceversa (that is string.hex2bytes and bytes[].tohex). I can provide them if you need them.

Comment: Why did you program the PadRight methods for decryption? If they are actually doing something they can only mess up the ciphertext.

Comment: I need it right that way for now. Later I will use PKCS7, but for now I need them that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;` in decryption method.

Comment: Hmm, a block encrypt method with a padding mode - correct answer of course, but a strange API if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

1. The code you are running includes [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29). Padding allows data that is not evenly divisible by the block size. In this example you are transforming a single block in which case you could change the padding mode to none `aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None` (as answered by Ulugbek Umirov)
2. The `ICryptoTransform.TransformBlock()` function returns the number of bytes written to the output this can be less than the block size must accommodate that case.
3. The `encryptor.TransformFinalBlock()` function should always be called last this may include additional bytes. This can be called with an empty byte array as input.

Given that you are only transforming a single block the simplest thing to do is to:

1. Add `aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None`
2. Change the following line

   > `encryptor.TransformBlock(msg_hex.hex2bytes(), 0, 16, output, 0);`
   >   to
   >   `output = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(msg_hex.hex2bytes(), 0, 16);`

Apologies for answering an old question but given that the current accepted answer is incomplete I thought it would be useful to provide the additional details.